# Scrollbar not appearing in the scrollpane when added to the panel

Tags: java, swing

**I have 2 tables each are added for a scrollpane however the scrollbar only apperas in one of them**

```
     JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
  JScrollPane pane_2 = new JScrollPane(table_1);
  table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
  table_1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

  panel.add(pane_2);

  panel.add(pane);
```

**the scrollbar only appears in pane_2 and not in pane**

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Such a small example has several advantages, one of which is that you'll possibly realize at which point of the reduction of your code the problem keeps/stops appearing, possibly giving you the solution straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason of such behavior could be different size of the tables. According to my experience `JScrollPane` shows the scrollbar only in case that its content is bigger and does not fit within the pane.

You can try to experiment with following [`JScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) properties:

- [`horizontalScrollBarPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(int))
- [`verticalScrollBarPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(int))

They can contain following values (e.g. in vertical case):

- `ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`
- `ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER`
- `ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`

They should control the behavior you ask about. The names are self explanatory I think.